# How to restore files deleted by chkdsk, are they stored somewhere?

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk

I killed retarded Windows by powering the PC off, I was in hurry. Than I booted into Linux and moved some files around. Than I rebooted into Win and forgot to press 'skip check', than chkdsk removed files with my project I was working for two hours. WTF Windows? Can I restore it without restoring tools?

Comment: After doing all the wrong things using a restore tool or backup is your best approach. You could look into the chk directory to see whenever it was moved there first (probably with a cryptic name).

Comment: chkdsk makes immediate and permanent change to the master file table, and previous states are not really stored.  This exists **fsutil usn readjournal c:**  However, after examining the data I feel it would be of minimal helpfulness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use testdisk or photorec by cgsecurity, or similar hard drive scanning utilities.

It will scrape together all the data from unused sectors.  Chkdsk may alter the MFT, and cause sectors to be unallocated.  However, unless the sector is needed to write a new data it doesn't intentionally erase the sectors it frees.  So some or all of your data might exist.  However, the longer you wait the more writes occur, and the probability of a successful outcome.

However:

1. It will find 1000's if not 10's of thousands of results.
2. Sifting through it will not be pleasant
3. The filenames will mainly be butchered
4. Due to file fragmentation, you may only get pieces of the files you want.

Think of your file like puzzle pieces the MFT ties a virtual string from one to the next to the next until you reach the end of the file.  Delete a file and all of the strings are removed, but there is no record on how the pieces were previously strung together.

5. Some file formats make it difficult or impossible to sucessfully reassemble the fragments.
6. This will take many hours, unless your super lucky

Comment: Doesn't it simply mean that Windows and its NTFS file system totally sucks and should be recycled?

Comment: @mevsme  No, filesystems are extremely complex and trade offs have to be made.  Take FAT12/16/32 vs NTFS for example hackers took advantage of having zero security with FAT, so a performance hit was accepted to implement security.  If the overhead either space, performance, or memory is too high nobody will use your file system.  The NTFS is the best trade off based on variety of trade offs microsoft had at the time.  Instead of taking a storage and performance hit for maintaining deleted records the user is left with the responsibility of making backups.

Comment: The BTRFS is a relatively new, but at least a couple years old, and it does maintain snapshots containing changed and deleted files.  However, it is regularly the slowest in a variety of benchmarks.  Also you regularly run out of free space on your volume, unless you have like 4x the amount of storage you need.  Then you have to spend time purging the snapshots, and deciding which ones to purge, or just giving up saying "the heck with it" and purging them all at once.

Comment: complexity is the enemy of reliability.  The more features you add the more complex the programming the less reliable it is especially in unusual circumstances like power failure,unexpected reboots, and etc.